# Is there a way to identify the TFS branch that was checked into in an Azure Devops CI build?

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, continuous-deployment, tfvc

I have a TFVC project with about 4 branches. I need to somehow setup build and release pipelines that build an artifact for each branch. Because I will eventually need to repeat this process elsewhere, I would like to prevent having to duplicate the same build pipelines for each branch. I am able to configure a single build pipeline that works on whatever branch I need using a user-defined variable when the pipeline is kicked off, but now I need to enable continuous integration on the build.

[My current build pipeline trigger configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8Itx.png)

I need this to work such that whenever someone checks into one of the TFVC branches, the build is kicked off and can correctly identify which branch was updated. From what I have found, this means that my initial idea of a user-defined variable is not going to work any longer. Is there a predefined pipeline variable that I can use to tell which branch was checked into, so that that branch is the one that is checked out and built? If not, is there some other way to do this in one pipeline, or do I ultimately need to duplicate this build pipeline for each branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, it's **not available** with TFVC in Azure DevOps/TFS build pipeline.

For CI trigger, you could select the version control paths you want to include and exclude. In most cases, you should make sure that these filters are consistent with your TFVC mappings on the Repository tab. It's not able to dynamically set workspace mapping path based on the branch which continuous integration trigger your build pipeline.

You could also take a look at Daniel's explanation in this question: [When my TFS build is triggered by a branch-specific check-in, why doesn't it set that branch as its source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53951032/when-my-tfs-build-is-triggered-by-a-branch-specific-check-in-why-doesnt-it-set)

> **TFVC relies on workspace mappings to know what to download.** The workspace mappings can encompass multiple TFVC repos across different
>   team projects, multiple branches within a single repository......
>
> As a result, there's no way for it to understand how to dynamically change workspace mappings to be for a specific branch.

Conclusion: You may need one build for every branch, duplicate the pipeline simply change the path filters in trigger and workspace mappings.